# Is there an analog for transaction commit in multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, transactions

I often have an impression that it is possible to draw a close analogy between transactions and threads. Indeed:

1. A transaction is a sequence of actions. A running thread is a sequence of statements.
2. Transactions read/modify rows and tables (in terms of relational databases). Threads read/modify class and static fields.
3. Transactions utilize [locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) to achieve data consistency. [So](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) do threads.

If the analogy really took place, it would be much easier for everyone to understand transactions using their knowledge about multithreading (and vice-versa).

However, there is a problem: there seems no close analogy for *transaction commit* (or *rollback*) in the world of multithreading.

Does it mean that the analogy in reality is just an illusion and it is better to not use knowledge about multithreading when learning transactions? Or there still is the analogy of commit/rollback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, it is possible to make a thread wait for other thread to die (see [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())). It seems that transaction's commit/rollback action is analogous to thread's death.